# Active/inactive users using checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, sqlyog

i need to update my database as soon as i check the checkbox with the value of 0(inactive) and 1(active). if i uncheck the checkbox the user would be unable to access the page means he/she is blocked from user panel. and if i check  the box again the user can be enable to access the whole web means he/she would be unblocked. 
i wonder if i can do this in codeigniter. i have searched for it but i cannot get them. Advance sorry it there is silly one.
Thankyou for any help.

**This is my view file :**

```
<div  class="col-main">
  <h1 class="page-title">All Users</h1>
  <div class="admin_panel">
    <ul class="form-fields">
      <li class="full-row">
        <table class="table demo">
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/admin_control/add_users" class="add">Add New</a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><label>Quick Search : </label>
              <input id="filter" type="text"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
        <table class="table demo table-bordered product_grid" data-filter="#filter">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S.No</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>last Name</th>
          <th>Password</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Password</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> <tr>

       <?php if(isset($pro_data) && $pro_data != false){ ;
        foreach ($pro_data as $da) { ?> 
          <td><?php echo $da['reg_id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $da['reg_fname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $da['reg_lname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $da['reg_pass']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $da['reg_email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $da['reg_pass']; ?></td>
          <td><?php $data = array(
                                  'name'        => 'reg_fname',
                                  'id'          => 'reg_id',
                                  'value'       => 'accept',
                                  'checked'     => TRUE,
                                  'style'       => 'margin:10px',
                                  );

                                  echo form_checkbox($data);?></td>




          <td class="edit"><a title="Edit" href="edit-user.php"><img title="Edit" alt="Edit" src="images/edit_icon.png"></a></td>
          <td class="del"><a title="Remove" href="#"><img title="Remove" alt="Remove" src="images/delete_item_btn.png"></a></td>                
        </tr>  
        <?php }?>
        <?php }?>
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a AJAX Request to the CodeIgniter Controller. The Controller updates the database. As soon as a User wants to visit the site, you check if he has the right to do.

If a user should be immediately get the new right (for example if he is on the forbidden site), you need Websockets.

I hope this helps. Your Question only gives little information about your Problem. Do you want immediately set rights (-> AJAX)? Why not a Form? Maybe I'm wrong and you ask for a completely different   causing.

Comment: i am trying exactly what you have said on first line. 

if there is any tutorial or sample code. please provide for the ajax

Comment: This ist a good tutorial on AJAX-Beginners: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp  If you want to get the ID Information you should read something about DOM. Or just search in Stackoverflow on "javascript is checkbox set"

Comment: Did it work out as you planed? What was your solution?